# Keep getting Unhandled promise rejection even with try catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, promise, parse-platform

I keep getting the following error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)

After looking up some solutions all I have to do is put my code within a try catch block, that you can see below but I still get this error, what am I doing wrong?

I am trying to update a column and set any arrays in it to an empty array.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("updateFollowedBy", async (request) => {
    try {
        var emptyArray = [];

        let date = new Date();
        let query = new Parse.Query("Categories");
    
        const results = await query.find({useMasterKey:true});
    
        results.forEach(object => {
            if (object.get("followedBy")) {
                object.set("followedBy", emptyArray);
            }
        });
        Parse.Object.saveAll(results);  
        return ("Successfully updated column on " + date); 
    } 
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: What error does your promise actually reject with? The part of the message you've shown only tells us that it's not handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unhandled rejected promise probably comes from the `Parse.Object.saveAll()` function since you are not awaiting this. Try with:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("updateFollowedBy", async (request) => {
    try {
        var emptyArray = [];

        let date = new Date();
        let query = new Parse.Query("Categories");
    
        const results = await query.find({useMasterKey:true});
    
        results.forEach(object => {
            if (object.get("followedBy")) {
                object.set("followedBy", emptyArray);
            }
        });
        await Parse.Object.saveAll(results);
        // You might want to pass { useMasterKey: true } option to make it work without exception: 
        //await Parse.Object.saveAll(results, { useMasterKey: true });
        return ("Successfully updated column on " + date); 
    } 
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```